# Openfire Smack Connection issue

Tags: java, ubuntu, openfire, smack

This is my first time using Openfire & smack. These are the details :

- Version:  Openfire 3.10.0
- Server Directory: /opt/openfire Server
- Name: ubuntu

Environment

- Java Version: 1.7.0_79 Oracle Corporation -- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
- Appserver:    jetty/9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
- Host Name:    ubuntu

I am using the latest version of Smack 4.1

And this is the code :

```
    public XMPPManager() 
{   
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setServiceName("ubuntu")
            //.setHost("127.0.0.1")
            .setPort(5222)
            .setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setDebuggerEnabled(true).build();

    AbstractXMPPConnection mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

    try 
    {
        System.out.println("connecting");
        mConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
        mConnection.connect();
        System.out.println("connected");
        mConnection.login("tuser1", "test1");

    } 
    catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Now when I am running this code I am getting following error :

```
    Java project working, Hello World !!
connecting
Jun 08, 2015 8:16:49 AM org.jivesoftware.smack.util.DNSUtil resolveDomain
WARNING: Exception while resovling SRV records for ubuntu. Consider adding '_xmpp-(server|client)._tcp' DNS SRV Records
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '_xmpp-client._tcp.ubuntu'
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.checkResponseCode(DnsClient.java:654)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.isMatchResponse(DnsClient.java:572)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:421)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:210)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:430)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:231)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:139)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:127)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.javax.JavaxResolver.lookupSRVRecords(JavaxResolver.java:78)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.DNSUtil.resolveDomain(DNSUtil.java:171)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.DNSUtil.resolveXMPPDomain(DNSUtil.java:120)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.populateHostAddresses(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:569)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:552)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:830)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:360)
    at XMPPManager.<init>(XMPPManager.java:29)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)

08:16:49 AM SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='ubuntu' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
08:16:49 AM RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="ubuntu" id="3197fe6e" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
connected
08:16:50 AM SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='DIGEST-MD5'>=</auth>
08:16:50 AM RECV (0): <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cmVhbG09InVidW50dSIsbm9uY2U9InFva3NTWFkveDZSQTh1bmJpb3FSQjZKY2NhSnhsd3JsNXBWZEVzakUiLHFvcD0iYXV0aCIsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCxhbGdvcml0aG09bWQ1LXNlc3M=</challenge>
08:16:50 AM SENT (0): <response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>Y2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCx1c2VybmFtZT0idHVzZXIxIixyZWFsbT0idWJ1bnR1Iixub25jZT0icW9rc1NYWS94NlJBOHVuYmlvcVJCNkpjY2FKeGx3cmw1cFZkRXNqRSIsbmM9MDAwMDAwMDEsY25vbmNlPSJoanlFaTl4N1BZTCtZb1VCQmZXRDJWNjF6M2doSzlBOW43Tlh6RDgyIixkaWdlc3QtdXJpPSJ4bXBwL3VidW50dSIsbWF4YnVmPTY1NTM2LHJlc3BvbnNlPTliMGM5YzBiOGNmYjVlOTYzNmI1ZDUyOWFlOTgwNThkLHFvcD1hdXRo</response>
08:16:50 AM RECV (0): <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cnNwYXV0aD02OGY5MTNhNDNmOWYyNzIxMTViM2I5YTc4ZDBhM2JlOA==</success>
08:16:50 AM SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='ubuntu' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' id='3197fe6e' xml:lang='en'>
08:16:50 AM RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="ubuntu" id="3197fe6e" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"><optional/></session></stream:features>
08:16:50 AM SENT (0): <iq id='hqopf-3' type='set'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'><resource>Smack</resource></bind></iq>
08:16:50 AM RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="hqopf-3" to="ubuntu/3197fe6e"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>tuser1@ubuntu/Smack</jid></bind></iq>
08:16:50 AM User logged (0): tuser1@ubuntu:5222/Smack
08:16:50 AM SENT (0): <iq id='hqopf-5' type='get'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'></query></iq>
08:16:50 AM RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="hqopf-5" to="tuser1@ubuntu/Smack"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
08:16:50 AM XMPPConnection authenticated (0)
08:16:50 AM SENT (0): <presence id='hqopf-7'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw='/></presence>
08:16:50 AM RECV (0): <iq type="get" id="360-5" to="tuser1@ubuntu/Smack" from="ubuntu"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
08:16:50 AM SENT (0): <iq to='ubuntu' id='360-5' type='result'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'><identity category='client' name='Smack' type='pc'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'/><feature var='jabber:iq:privacy'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/><feature var='vcard-temp'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:time'/><feature var='jabber:iq:last'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:ping'/><feature var='jabber:x:data'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/xdata-validate'/><feature var='jabber:iq:version'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/xdata-layout'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:receipts'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></query></iq>
08:16:50 AM RECV (0): <presence id="hqopf-7" from="tuser1@ubuntu/Smack" to="tuser1@ubuntu/Smack"><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack" ver="NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw="/></presence><presence from="testuser2@ubuntu" to="tuser1@ubuntu" type="subscribe"/>
```

What is going wrong. I cannot see any sessions on the openfire admin console. The server is setup on Ubuntu 12.04.3 (localhost)

Comment: did you try to connect via (tuser1@hostername.com, password)?

Comment: I tried tuser1@ubuntu, password it gives the same result.

Comment: In order to use an external xmpp client, you should have your SRV records. (dns for web and srv for chat servers). So that your chat account will be accessible via username@chat.website.com

Comment: thanks for the info.. can you please tell me how to setup these records if I have the openfire server setup on my locahost (ubuntu). Or is there any tutorial or link that can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your connection settings are wrong, here use this :

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .setServiceName("127.0.0.1")
        .setHost("127.0.0.1")
        .setPort(5222)
        .setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled)
        .setDebuggerEnabled(true).build();
```